# Aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I want to generate a report based on a monthly count of records. In situations where there's none, I want to have 0 return instead of nothing. The issue is, the query below throws an error **aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY**. Any help will be appreciated.

```
SELECT sc.name, d.months, COUNT(s.scan_type) AS scan_count FROM 
    (SELECT CAST('2018-02-21 12:45:44+00' AS TIMESTAMP) - date_trunc('month', CAST('2018-02-21 12:45:44+00' AS TIMESTAMP) - offs) AS months 
FROM generate_series(CAST('2018-02-21 12:45:44+00' AS TIMESTAMP), CAST(now() AS TIMESTAMP), INTERVAL '1 month') AS offs ) d 
LEFT OUTER JOIN scans s ON d.months = date_trunc('month', s.datetime) 
INNER JOIN schools sc ON s.school_id = sc.id 
GROUP BY sc.name, d.months, scan_count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing **INNER JOIN** to **LEFT OUTER JOIN** on *schools* fixed it. Also, I had to remove *scan_count* from the **GROUP BY** clause.

```
SELECT sc.name, d.months, COUNT(s.scan_type) AS scan_count FROM 
    (SELECT CAST('2018-02-21 12:45:44+00' AS TIMESTAMP) - date_trunc('month', CAST('2018-02-21 12:45:44+00' AS TIMESTAMP) - offs) AS months 
FROM generate_series(CAST('2018-02-21 12:45:44+00' AS TIMESTAMP), CAST(now() AS TIMESTAMP), INTERVAL '1 month') AS offs ) d 
LEFT OUTER JOIN scans s ON d.months = date_trunc('month', s.datetime) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN schools sc ON s.school_id = sc.id 
GROUP BY sc.name, d.months
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, use `CROSS JOIN` to combine all the dates and `schools`.  Then bring in the original data and aggregate:

```
SELECT sc.name, d.months, COUNT(s.scan_type) AS scan_count 
FROM generate_series(CAST('2018-02-21 12:45:44+00' AS TIMESTAMP), 
                     CAST(now() AS TIMESTAMP),
                     INTERVAL '1 month'
                    ) d CROSS JOIN
     schools sc LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     scans s 
     ON d.months = date_trunc('month', s.datetime) AND
        s.school_id = sc.id 
GROUP BY sc.name, d.months;
```

Comment: Your query breaks with an error **syntax error at or near "d"**. The **)** before **d CROSS JOIN**. Removing it doesn't work either.

Comment: @RobertWilson . . . I fixed the syntax issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a NVL ?
For example

```
SELECT sc.name, d.months, NVL(COUNT(s.scan_type),COUNT(s.scan_type),0) AS scan_count FROM ...
```

Comment: NVL() is not supported (by default) by PostgreSQL, that's Oracle only (I think). You could use COALESCE(), that also works in Oracle.